# Check Points in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008, ssis-2005

I got question from interview!!!
***How to achieve Check point functionality in SSIS with out using check point***.
If package fails it has to be re-run from the point that it failed instead of rerunning the entire package.***without using check point***.

Answer (score 0):

one way is create a task dispatcher as entry point in the control flow. This will only keep track of the last task successfully executed and call the next task depending on that persisted variable. The first time it runs the variable would be 0 and therefore it will start in the first task, if the first task completes successfully the variable will be set to 1. If the task 2 fails, then the next time the control flows run it will restart on task1 and so on... the control flow will look like this:

[image]